# Support dates with optional month and day in angular date input or uib-dateparser

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I want to support the dates in the following formats in my angular bootstrap input: `YYYY`, `MM.YYYY` and `DD.MM.YYYY`. At the same time I want to send to the server the dates in the following formats: `YYYY`, `YYYY-MM`, `YYYY-MM-DD`. The user enters the date from the keyboard, no datepicker is needed. Is there an easy way to do that? I saw [uib-dateparser](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/dateparser), but it seems that it doesn't support optional `MM` and `DD`.

Comment: Use $filter('date'). https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: how can I support more than one format with it?